# How to combine Completable with Single in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm building an application that is caching data from the internet, when the phone is offline it will show the offline items(this functionality works as intended). Now I have a difficulty to include a refresh option(I will basically will delete the items that I have in the cache and try to fetch more recent items). I have two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to combine Completable with Single it gives me an error
   none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
2. I'm not sure how to pass arguments to a function getWeather in andThen operator.

My Code:

*WeatherRepository*

```
fun deleteWeatherForecast(lat : Double, lng: Double) : Completable
{
    return lWeatherRepo.deleteWeatherForecast(lat,lng)
            .andThen(rWeatherRepo::getWeather(lat,lng))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

LocalWeatherRepository

```
fun deleteWeatherForecast(lat: Double, lng: Double) : Completable
{
    return weatherDao.deleteForecastByLocation(lat,lng)
}
```

RemoteWeatherRepository

```
fun getWeather(lat: Double, lng: Double): Single<Weather> {
    val locationStr = String.format("%f,%f",lat,lng)
    return weatherService.getWeatherForecastResponse(API_KEY,locationStr)
}
```

I chose Completable because I want to wait till the deletion will be completed and fetch the next it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your WeatherRepository like this

```
fun deleteWeatherForecast(lat : Double, lng: Double) : Completable
{
    return lWeatherRepo.deleteWeatherForecast(lat,lng)
            .andThen(rWeatherRepo.getWeather(lat,lng))  // answer question 2
            .ignoreElement() // answer question 1, convert single to completable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```